# aws-xray-sdk on a lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I see that I can enable x-ray tracing on my lambda function just by checking a checkbox (or setting Tracing: Active if using SAM).
That adds a high level logging.

If I want more detailed logging, my understanding is that I need to add:

```
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder
from aws_xray_sdk.core import patch_all
patch_all()
```

however, the xry sdk is not part of  lambda. Clearly one of the solutions is to install it with `pip install aws-xray-sdk -t .` but that will add 42Mb to the function's code.

Is there an alternative solution?
thanks

Comment: What is your original bundle size before adding X-Ray SDK? If this single module design produces a big overhead to your function code, you can open an issue at the SDK repo https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python with your use case so it can be properly addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the X-Ray Python SDK is written as a single package, and there are no current work arounds to reduce the payload size.

Comment: This is only true for Python right? The other runtimes like nodejs and java are included as part of the lambda? Where can I read more on this? I couldn't find it from the aws docs

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda layers to bake the X-Ray SDK to your runtime to keep your function code small. See more details on lambda layers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html. Please let me know if you have extra concerns on using layers.

Comment: that is what I ended up doing - I was just hoping that there was an easier way, Thanks